# Facebook's friends smash game is not picking friends to smash

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas

I made a reskin of Facebook's Unity game sample. When I uploaded it to Facebook canvas and play the API is not picking any Facebook friends to smash.

What can I do to resolve this? I did not change anything in [MainMenu.cs](https://github.com/fbsamples/friendsmash-unity/blob/master/friendsmash_payments_complete/Assets/Scripts/MainMenu.cs.meta).

Here is a game : https://apps.facebook.com/smashhyourfriend

Comment: So you did a "reskin"? What happens if you change nothing at all and then try it? Does it work then or still nothing?

Comment: I change its graphics and open graph object id's for payment.In payment.cs